# How to get audio file duration in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio

I noticed Safari is a bit unpredictable with getting an audio file's duration. I've written the below code to fetch and store the duration of an MP3 file:

```
  // Get duration and store it in the DB
  let audio = document.createElement('audio');

  audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function ({target}) {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.volume = 1;

    Meteor.call('util/setTrackDuration', track._id, target.duration);
  });
  audio.src = track.getTrackUrl();

  // This stuff is because of Safari.. psh!
  audio.volume = 0;
  audio.play();
```

You can see I had to add some code because merely setting `audio.src` to a URL is not always enough in Safari, though it works fine in Firefox and Chrome and fires off the `loadedmetadata` event every time. In Safari, it only works about half the time for some reason.

Is there a reason `loadedmetadata` is not reliably fired off in Safari once the `audio.src` is set to a URL? It's really a waste of bandwidth to have to invoke `audio.play()` just to get the audio file duration (I'm using Amazon S3). Is this a bug? And is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to reload after the changing the source using load() explicitly. see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp:

> The load() method is used to update the audio/video element after
>   changing the source or other settings.

I think you might want to give that a shot.

```
audio.src = track.getTrackUrl();
audio.load();
```

Overall, this html5 audio element is a bit buggy in my experience. If you don't mind some extra javascript, try using a jQuery player like JPlayer for now and use html5 audio when it is implemented correctly in all browsers.

As for the reason of this behaviour: setting the src will probably make the browser start loading the file asynchronously. Calling play() when the loading is not done, the loadedmetadata listener seems to be skipped by sasfari and instead the canplay event is called. You can remedy this maybe by using `Audio.preload = 'metadata'` and then calling `load()`.